# How can I open a stuck, overfilled kitchen drawer that doesn't have a horizontal entry point?

Tags: kitchens, drawers

Slightly different to other questions I've seen.

Solutions to them have you put something through the small gap (ruler, coat hanger, straw, anything).

However, ours has a slight vertical dip before it goes horizontal. Which means anything we slide into the very small gap goes straight down and touches the bottom of the drawer, rather than heads towards the back of it to get what's stuck.

It's a built in drawer in a new build house, so is hard (and maybe impossible) to take apart. There is no drawer next to it.

Any ideas to help me out would be amazing.

Comment: Are there drawers below it or above it?

Answer (score 2):

If there are drawers above or below, fully remove them and attempt to access that way, reaching around.

If not, try pounding on the drawer face with a rubber mallet (or something else that won't damage the finish) to try to get the drawer contents to shift a little.

Finally, you can put a 90 degree bend in a chunk of wire (coathanger or whatever) and slip that wire (with the bent part **horizontal**) into the "tiny gap", then **rotate** the wire to manipulate the stuff in the drawer. You may want an opposing 90 dregree bend on the vertical part sticking out of the drawer to act as a handle. The bent part going inside needs to be shorter than the drawer is wide, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Drill a hole in the front of the drawer near the top but so the hole allows access into the inside of the drawer. (If there are other drawers of the same construction in the house, use one or more to determine the correct place to drill.)

Insert a borescope through the hole to see how it is jammed. Use a probe in that hole or another hole to relieve the jam.

Comment: Could that be done from below?